# How to set a background picture only to 90% of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am currently working on my first android app and I have a background picture. The app just shows quotes from people and it has 4 buttons at the bottom of the screen.

This is my current state:

[image]

As you can see (or cannot see), the buttons are not really visible. I want them to be black, but have a white background behind them. I was thinking of setting the background to 80% or 90% of the screen, if thats possible. But I couldn't find information on that.

My idea was something like this:

[image]

Of course I don't want this white block at the top.

Can you point me to the right direction how to do this?

Thank you for every answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I was thinking of setting the background to 80% or 90% of the screen*

Use `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"` together with `constraintLayout` :

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**It will look like this**

[image]

### Updated answer

```
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want this white block at the top, just at the bottom. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Do you want the image to cover the entire screen?

Comment: From the top - 80 %, so that only my buttons dont have the background. But the top still has the background

Comment: Delete `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"` from the image view and tell me if this work for you

Comment: And in button3 change `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"` to     `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.2"`

Comment: May you update your answer? I will check your solution later, thank you already!